# how to define a general conditional for a complete text

Tags: conditionals

I wonder how to define a newcommand of the type with general conditionnal

```
\def\a{}
```

which givefor each call in the text

```
%\begin{comment}

%\end{comment}
```

when `a=0` and

```
\begin{comment}

\end{comment}
```

for any other value of `a`

Thanks

Comment: Have you heard of `comment` package?

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "call in the text"?  How would the source code look like, and how should the result look like?